# Cleaning up code with methods

Tags: java, for-loop, methods, repeat

I have created a mitsubishi logo builder as shown below. It takes input from the `logo.txt` file and uses those `ints/chars` to create however many logos that are identified in the `logo.txt` file. I just feel that my code is very repetitive and I would like to clean it up in terms of cutting it into separate methods instead of repeating over and over, are there any reccomemndations on how to clean this up?  I would appreciate any and all feedback. Or even just a starting point. Thank you in advance.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    try {
        input = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("config.txt"));
        //initialize ithe variable's input and output
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
        System.exit(0);

    }

    int size = Integer.parseInt(inputStream.nextLine());
    int numLogos = Integer.parseInt(inputStream.nextLine());
    char letter1 =  inputStream.next().charAt(0);
    char letter2 =  inputStream.next().charAt(0); 

    for(int bee = numLogos; bee > 0; bee--){ 
        for(int y = 0; y < size; y++) { 

            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < size - y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < size - y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }

            for(int x = size; x > y; x--) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter1);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter1);
            }
            for(int x = size; x > y; x--) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }

            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < size - y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < size - y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }           
        for(int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < size - y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < size - y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }

            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }            
            for(int x = 0; x < size - y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter1);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < size - y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter1);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }

            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < size - y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < size - y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for(int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
            for(int x = size; x > y; x--) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter1);
            }

            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter1);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < size - y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter1);
            }

            for(int x = size; x > y; x--) {
                System.out.print(letter1);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }

            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }            
            for(int x = 0; x < size - y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter1);
            }

            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter1);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < size - y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter1);
            }

            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter1);
            }
            for(int x = size; x > y; x--) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This might be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is code-review. Should be in http://codereview.stackexchange.com instead

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is code-review. Should be in codereview.stackexchange.com instead

Answer (score 0):

You use this many times in the code:

```
        for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
            System.out.print(letter2);
        }
        for(int x = 0; x < size - y; x++) {
            System.out.print(letter2);
        }
        for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
            System.out.print(letter2);
        }
        for(int x = 0; x < size - y; x++) {
            System.out.print(letter2);
        }
```

It can be replaced by

```
        for(int x = 0; x < 2*size; x++) {
            System.out.print(letter2);
        }
```

Also, this:

```
        for(int x = 0; x < size - y; x++) {
            System.out.print(letter1);
        }
        for(int x = 0; x < size - y; x++) {
            System.out.print(letter1);
        }
```

Can be replaced by

```
        for(int x = 0; x < 2*(size - y); x++) {
            System.out.print(letter1);
        }
```